# Copy 'Animate property' keyframe to multiple objects

Tags: animation, objects

Hi I have a ton of objects in my scene that have rigid body positional keyframes baked onto them. I now want to animate the viewport and render visibility of the objects however I only seem to be able to change the keyframe with the active object that is selected, not the entire selection.

Is there a way around this so I do not have to apply the visibility keyframes to every object (there are 100+)?

I know I can ctrl L/animation data however this would also copy all the positional keyframe data from the selected object to everything and I only want to copy the visibility?